# OPENGL GLEW Can someone help me to set my cylinder horizontal

Tags: c++

Can someone help me set up my cylinder horizontal. My library is GLEW. If you need more detail about the code I can provide it.

```cpp
void UCreateSpeaker(GLfloat verts[], GLushort indices[], int numSides, float radius, float halfLen) {
    const float TWO_PI = 2.0f * 3.1415926f;
    const float radiansPerSide = TWO_PI / numSides;

    int currentVertex = 0;

    verts[0] = 0.0f;        //0 X
    verts[1] = halfLen;     //0 Y
    verts[2] = 0.0f;        //0 Z
    verts[3] = 0.0f;        //0 R
    verts[4] = 0.0f;        //0 G    
    verts[5] = 0.0f;        //0 B
    verts[6] = 1.0f;        //0 A
    currentVertex++;
    verts[7] = 0.0f;        //1 X
    verts[8] = -halfLen;    //1 Y
    verts[9] = 0.0f;        //1 Z
    verts[10] = 0.0f;       //1 R
    verts[11] = 0.0f;       //1 G
    verts[12] = 0.0f;       //1 B
    verts[13] = 1.0f;       //1 A
    currentVertex++;

    // Track of Triangles Added
    int currentTriangle = 0;
    for (int edge = 0; edge < numSides; edge++) {

        // Calculate the Center Point to the Next Vertex
        float theta = ((float)edge) * radiansPerSide;

        verts[currentVertex * STRIDE + 0] = radius * cos(theta);    // X
        verts[currentVertex * STRIDE + 1] = halfLen;                // Y
        verts[currentVertex * STRIDE + 2] = radius * sin(theta);    // Z
        verts[currentVertex * STRIDE + 3] = 1.0f;                   // R
        verts[currentVertex * STRIDE + 4] = 0.0f;                   // G
        verts[currentVertex * STRIDE + 5] = 0.0f;                   // B
        verts[currentVertex * STRIDE + 6] = 1.0f;                   // A
        currentVertex++;

        verts[currentVertex * STRIDE + 0] = radius * cos(theta);    // X
        verts[currentVertex * STRIDE + 1] = -halfLen;               // Y
        verts[currentVertex * STRIDE + 2] = radius * sin(theta);    // Z
        verts[currentVertex * STRIDE + 3] = 1.0f;                   // R
        verts[currentVertex * STRIDE + 4] = 0.0f;                   // G
        verts[currentVertex * STRIDE + 5] = 0.0f;                   // B
        verts[currentVertex * STRIDE + 6] = 1.0f;                   // A
        currentVertex++;

        //Indices for the Triangles
        if (edge > 0) {

            // Top triangle
            indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 0] = 0;                 // Center-Top Prisim
            indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 1] = currentVertex - 4; // Upper-Left Side
            indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 2] = currentVertex - 2; // Upper Right Side
            currentTriangle++;

            // Bottom Triangle
            indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 0] = 1;                 // Center-Top Prisim
            indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 1] = currentVertex - 3; // Upper-Left Side
            indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 2] = currentVertex - 1; // Upper Right Side
            currentTriangle++;

            // Triangle for 1/2 Rectangular Side
            indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 0] = currentVertex - 4; // Upper-Left Side
            indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 1] = currentVertex - 3; // Bottom-Left Side
            indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 2] = currentVertex - 1; // Bottom-Right Side
            currentTriangle++;

            // Traingle for Second 1/2 rectangular Side
            indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 0] = currentVertex - 1; // Bottom-Right Side
            indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 1] = currentVertex - 2; // Upper-Right Side
            indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 2] = currentVertex - 4; // Upper-Left Side
            currentTriangle++;
        }
    }

    // Indices for Triangles

    // Top Triangle
    indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 0] = 0;                         // Center Top Prims
    indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 1] = currentVertex - 2;         // Upper-Left Side
    indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 2] = 2;                         // Fist Upper-Left (Change to Right)
    currentTriangle++;

    // Bottom Triangle
    indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 0] = 1;                         //Center-Bottom Prism
    indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 1] = currentVertex - 1;         //Bottom-Left Side
    indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 2] = 3;                         // Fist Bottom-Left (Change to Right)
    currentTriangle++;

    // First Triangle 1/2 Rectangular Side
    indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 0] = currentVertex - 2;         // Upper-Left Side
    indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 1] = currentVertex - 1;         //Bottom-Left Side
    indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 2] = 3;                         // Bottom-Right Side
    currentTriangle++;

    // Second Triangle 1/2 Rectangular Side
    indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 0] = 3;                         // Bottom-Right Side
    indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 1] = 2;                         // Upper-Right Side
    indices[(3 * currentTriangle) + 2] = currentVertex - 2;         // Upper-Left Side
    currentTriangle++;
}
```

Comment: Instead of fussing around and generating it in the right orientation, why not apply a rotation to the vertexes?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: How do you do that or where should I place it?

Comment: You use a transformation matrix and apply it to each vertex in the vertex shader.

Comment: https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations